# SSRS timeout issue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have SSRS reports displayed on asp.net site which runs fine. The problem occurs when user has opened the report and kept the screen as it is for some time like 15-20 minuets and then when he does some activity on the report screen like postback or so, the following error occurs

**The report execution r3fwifezzfm2qoe3anvp0n55 has expired or cannot be found. (rsExecutionNotFound)**

Note: the session for the site is still active.

The error persists even after setting the **Report Timeout** setting in site setting of report server.

Please tell me for any possible solution for this error asap.

Answer (score 2):

You can set timeout in your `ConnectionString` like below:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" 
 connectionString="Data Source=your datasource;Initial Catalog=yourdbname;Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Password=yourpassword;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=5000;Connect Timeout=0" 
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```